# What type of Axios Error has config.retry?

Tags: typescript, axios

`axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => response, (error) => {//code})`

error.config comes across as AxiosRequestConfig, but that definitively does NOT have a retry or retryCount property, so it is definitely wrong. What is the correct type here?